# Execute part of php script from button

Tags: php

If you take a look at CMD you can use code like this:

```
A: 
echo "Hello"
goto A
```

In PHP I want to be able to do the same thing but when a button is pressed

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input placeholder="Label Name" name="label"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="submit me!" />
</form>


<?php

require_once("lib/block_io.php");

$apiKey = "";
$version = 2;
$pin = "";
$block_io = new BlockIo($apiKey, $pin, $version);

$label = htmlspecialchars( $_POST['label'] );
$newaddress = $block_io->get_new_address(array('label' => $label));



echo "Address: ".$newaddress->data->address;

----------------------------------------------

$addressbalance = $block_io->get_address_balance(array('labels' => $label));

?>
<br>
<button >I submited</button>
```

Below the dashed line is the code I want to execute from the button (Bottom)

Should I make a whole new page or have a separate thing like > then another

Answer (score 0):

Just like in javascript, you can have functions in php. Make the bottom part a seperate function and call it using your button's `onclick` attribute.